# org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext not able to load file

Tags: apache-spark, docker, cassandra

I having a simple Spark job, which reads values from a pipe separated file and do some business logic on it and write the processed value in our DB.

So to load the file, I am using `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext`. This is the code that I having to load the file as `DataFrame`

```
 DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "false")
            .option("comment", null)
            .option("delimiter", "|")
            .option("quote", null)
            .load(pathToTheFile);
```

Now the issue is 
1. The `load` function was not able to load the file
2. It is not giving much details(exception) about the issue, except in my console I get

```
WARN  2017-11-07 17:26:40,108 akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@172.17.0.2:35359] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
ERROR 2017-11-07 17:26:40,134 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 0
```

and it keeps on polling.

I am sure, the file is available in the expected folder with right format. But no idea what is this log is and why `SQLContext` could able to load the file.

Here is my build.gradle's dependencies section:

```
dependencies {

provided(
        [group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '1.4.0'],
        [group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.10', version: '1.4.0'],
        [group: 'com.datastax.spark', name: 'spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10', version: '1.4.0']
)

    compile([
            [group: 'com.databricks', name: 'spark-csv_2.10', version: '1.4.0'],
    ])


}
```

And I am running this job inside `docker` container

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The problem is related to running Spark inside of a Docker container. Because AKKA does not know to which IP to bind, it gets confused and therefore some timeouts occur.

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong Anything I can do about it??

Comment: Are you running only on your local machine, or on a cluster? How do you submit the job?

Comment: Does this link help your query? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930974/3078856

Answer (score 1):

You can check if that issue is not the same [as this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/spark-with-docker-errors-with-akka-NAT-td7702.html):

> [Long story](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Comprehensive-Port-Configuration-reference-tt5384.html#none) short, akka opens up dynamic, [random ports for each job](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security).  So, simple NAT fails.
>   You might try some trickery with a DNS server and docker's `--net=host`.
>
> Based on Jacob's suggestion, I started using `--net=host` which is a new option in latest version of docker.
>   I also set `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` to the host's IP address and then AKKA does not use the hostname and I don't need the Spark driver's hostname to be resolvable.

You can also compare your Dockerfile with the one used in [P7h/docker-spark 2.2.0](https://github.com/P7h/docker-spark/blob/master/Dockerfile) to see if there are any difference which might explain that issue.

Comment: I tried using --net=host `docker run --name suganth-job --net=host  -v /Users/smpillai/env/sparkjob:/var/lib/spark-dataload/ -d luketillman/datastax-enterprise:4.8.12 -k`. For some reason container could not able run.